# GRASS 7.2.1 r.denoise/mdenoise error Windows 10

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

So I am trying to use the r.denoise add on in GRASS 7.2.1 to remove noise from a .dem elevation model.

Initially when running the add on I received the error:

```
ERROR: mdenoise required. Follow instructions in html manual page to install it (g.manual r.denoise).
```

So I downloaded mdenoise.exe from the r.denoise page and added it to PATH in my environmental variables after placing it in a OsGeo4W/Bin and also tried putting it into the Grass 7.2.1 bin folder. Yet the error still persists...

I noticed that with Linux systems they recommend compiling the mdenoise from source. Should I have to install something like gg++ to compile and then try again? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

According to the mdenoise page (http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/neil.mitchell/mdenoise/) you need to compile it yourself on Linux which requires a C++ compiler. Then install the resulting binary, i.e. copy it into a directory listed the $PATH.

If it was free and open software we could simply bundle it. But so far it is not (http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Page342.htm).

Comment: Thanks for this, so I can compile it on a Linux VM then simply copy the resulting binary file to Windows? I will try this and let you know if it works!

Comment: No, a Linux binary only works on Linux. For Windows, download and unzip WinMDenoise.zip from Cardiff University Mesh Filtering group website (the Windows executable is MDenoise.exe).